# Conditionally working with variables in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is a small challenge within a big project, so I'm going to try to keep this simple.

I'm attempting to conditionally add columns to a `data.table`, and then process them on a conditional basis.

```
x <- T
y <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)))

y[  # filter some rows
  a != 1
][  # conditionally add two calculated columns
  ,
  if(x){
    `:=` (
      c = a*b,
      d = 1/b
    )
  }
][  # process columns and group
  ,
  list(
    a = sum(a),
    b = sum(b),
    if(x) c = sum(c)  # only add c if it's created above
  ),
  by = if(x) list(b, d) else list(b)  # only group by d if it's created above
]
```

Here is the output (error references the second set `[]`):

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'd' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In deconstruct_and_eval(m, envir, enclos) :
  Caught and removed `{` wrapped around := in j. := and `:=`(...) are 
                defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Of course, the error is a symptom of the warning. How can I get this done?

---

As @Michal pointed out, putting the `if()` statement outside the `data.table` call is an option:

```
if(x) {
  y[
   ...
  ]
} else {
  y[
   ...
  ]
}
```

I'm hoping there's a way to get this done without repeating the code in its entirety, to simplify everything.

Comment: why not take the if statement outside? like `if(x) { y[....`

Comment: I have my code working that way now, but it means 24 extra lines of code that are largely irrelevant. I'm just hoping there's a simple way to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing it inside the `j-expression`, because of how `:=` gets evaluated in there (it really only works if it's at the root of the expression tree), but you could put it in the `i-expression` as a workaround:

```
x = FALSE
y[a != 1][x, `:=`(c = a * b, d = 1/b)][]
#    a b
#1:  2 1
#2:  3 1
#3:  4 1
#4:  5 1
#5:  6 2
#6:  7 2
#7:  8 2
#8:  9 2
#9: 10 2

x = TRUE
y[a != 1][x, `:=`(c = a * b, d = 1/b)][]
#    a b  c   d
#1:  2 1  2 1.0
#2:  3 1  3 1.0
#3:  4 1  4 1.0
#4:  5 1  5 1.0
#5:  6 2 12 0.5
#6:  7 2 14 0.5
#7:  8 2 16 0.5
#8:  9 2 18 0.5
#9: 10 2 20 0.5
```

---

Since `c(1)` is the same as `c(1, NULL)`, it can be used to return complete vectors when you're not sure how many elements will compose them.

To conditionally include columns in `j`

```
y[
  ,
  c(
    list(
      a = sum(a), 
      b = sum(b)
    ), 
    if(x) list(c = sum(c))
  )
]
```

And to conditionally include columns in `by`

```
y[
  ,
  ...,
  by = c("b", if(x) "d")
]
```

`by` won't accept a `vector` of `list`s, but it will accept a `vector` of column names.

Comment: Actually - I'm now having issues with the last `[]` call, because in the `x <- F` scenario `c` and `d` don't show up. Could you take a look at the whole problem? I'll change the question so that it's broader.

Comment: @Chris you'll need to separate out the condition, e.g.: `y[a != 1][x, \`:=\`(c = a * b, d = 1/b)][, c(list(a = sum(a), b = sum(b)), if(x) list(c = sum(c)))]`, as for the `by` part - I'm not sure - I get a weird error there and it's probably a bug

Comment: Got the solution for this - `by` can be a vector of column names, so it's simply `by = c("b", if(x) "d")`. Very interesting that `all.equal(c(1), c(1, NULL))`. That may come in handy at some point. Thanks for all your help.